# window.history.pushState not Working in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

window.history.pushState not working after updating `jest :29.x.x` and installing `jest-environment-jsdom :29.x.x`.
below code works fine in jest 27.5.0.

```
    window.history.pushState({}, 'Test page', '/123')
    expect(window.location.href).toEqual('http://localhost/123')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following documentation might help you to mock with **pushState** and **replaceState** in jest:
https://gist.github.com/the0neWhoKnocks/bdac1d09b93b8418d948558f7ab233d7